# Django Rest Framework, making available internally or not

Tags: angular, api, django-rest-framework

I have a couple of docker containers, a Django Rest Framework API endpoint and an Angular front end that consumes the API.

Will I be able to connect to the API endpoint only internally (not expose over internet) using the docker service name, e.g.

Instead of using:

```
 base_url: 'https://example.com/api', //#LIVE
```

Use:

```
base_url: 'https://api:8000', //#using the docker service name for the api
```

I also need to consider if this is the best way of doing this since in the future the API will also need to be consumed by an iOS and Android app. Or is it better just to secure the API and use it across the internet (API gateway, JSW etc)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the service to be available locally, you should specify that in your `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. 
In the long run, you are better of securing the API with a proper authentication system that will only accept your official clients and deny access to others